# Custom cron job doesn't scheduled in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

I read several questions here and from Google search results, but I wasn't able to make it work. I have a function I want to run once every day which will fetch data from external source and store it on options page.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'update_stock_market' );
add_action( 'get_stock_market_daily_data', 'get_stock_market_data', 1, 1 );

function update_stock_market() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'get_stock_market_daily_data' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'get_stock_market_daily_data', array($company) );
    }
}

function get_stock_market_data($company ) {
    //do something here to get $data;
    update_option( 'stock_market_data', $data); 
}
```

However, no matter what happens, I cannot find the scheduled cron in the `wp-options` table under the `option-name` of `cron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me on a clean instance of WordPress, instead of looking directly in the database have you tried using the plugin WP Crontrol? Alternatively, with debug enabled, try adding a log entry to you update_stock_market function to check that the sechudled event is being called.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'update_stock_market' );
add_action( 'get_stock_market_daily_data', 'get_stock_market_data', 1, 1 );

function update_stock_market() {
    error_log( 'triggered' );
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'get_stock_market_daily_data' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'get_stock_market_daily_data', array($company) );
    }
}

function get_stock_market_data($company ) {
    //do something here to get $data;
    update_option( 'stock_market_data', $data); 
}
```

Comment: Good idea. I made it work with the debugging. There was another error that made that part of the code to never reach. However, I tried the WP Control as you suggested and it shows that the event is scheduled twice. And every time I refresh the page, another event is added. Any idea?

Comment: Its because of the undefined variable $company in the update_stock_market function, I cannot say specificaly why but if you set or remove this variable then only one scheduled event is created.

Comment: ^^  its because of the wp_next_scheduled secondary parameter is an array containing each separate argument to pass to the hook's callback function. Although not passed to a callback, these arguments are used to uniquely identify the event

Comment: therefore if you wanted to create a sceduled event for each company you could pass this as the secondary event, to create a unique event for each. more info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_next_scheduled/